# Espresso Automation : How to get the current index of an item in recyclerview. The viewholder is refreshed after scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I'm new to espresso test automation on android.
Below is my question.
Once I swipe/ scroll on my screen, on a recycler view, the view holder refreshes the current holder with the new items(as is the behavior of the recyclerview according to my understanding).
How do I click on the correct index of the item after the view is refreshed. Below is the code sample. i'm using a while loop to traverse through the items.

```
while (j < i - 1) { //i IS THE TOTAL NO. OF ITEMS IN THE VIEW
            Matcher<View> assetTimeInfo = allOf(isDescendantOfA(nthChildOf(recyclerView1, j)), withId(R.id.my_info));
            Matcher<View> assetName = allOf(isDescendantOfA(nthChildOf(recyclerView1, j)), isAssignableFrom(ImageView.class), withId(R.id.my_image));
            if (!(MyHelper.getText(assetTimeInfo)).equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                ChannelName = MyHelper.getContentDescription(assetName);
                Print("Channel Name :", "Found linear asset : " + ChannelName);
                onView(recyclerView1).perform(RecyclerViewActions.<BaseAdapter.VH>actionOnItemAtPosition(j, click()));
                break;
            } else {
                    onView(recyclerView1).perform(leftSwipe());// HERE THE ORIGINAL ITEM INDICES ARE MESSED UP
            }
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: We need more information. What does the _leftSwipe_ do to your RecyclerView? It's not clear, and as you indicated, this is where the problem originates. Also, you may want to remove the parts of the code in your question which do not help us solve your problem.